# ES6 Tail Call Optimization in Nashorn?

Tags: java, ecmascript-6, tail-recursion

Given that **ES6 support is being worked on in Nashorn team** and lack of proper Tail Call Optimization in JVM, how is this problem being tackled?

I know that the topic of Tail Calls has been debated to death so I'm much more interested in any workaround that Nashorn applies to be ES6 compliant.

With languages like ES6, Clojure and Scala - JVM is working really hard NOT to get TCO. Is there any useful resource I can follow to learn more about the Nashorn implementation and workarounds - ***I'm primarily interested in Nashorn and ES6+ support on JVM.***

Comment: Do you mean ***Java** is working really hard NOT to get TCO* ? As you see, scala and clojure are running on the JVM?! So it is not a platform thing, but a java language thing.

Comment: Oh, let me edit then. I mean, since JVM byte code doesn't have that `tail` instruction the Functional languages can't really hit that gold. Though with `trampoline` and compiler tricks Scala, Clojure do get pretty close. But my question is primarily Nashorn and ES6 related.

Comment: I guess they will use the same kinds of transformations as the other compilers and/or interpreters.

Comment: But that's not complete, you know. Both Clojure and Scala have to be *told explicitely* to look out for TCO but ES6 spec defines them as being implicit. Interesting situation...

Comment: @AbhinavSharma Actually Scala does it automatically too. The `@tailrec` annotation guarantees that the annotated method will be optimized *if it compiles*, but a method that compiles with that annotation will also be optimized without the annotation. I don't know about Clojure and ES6 though.

Comment: @Jasper-M Hmm, well Clojure has this ` loop .. recur` construction but ES6 has to have it in-built. Besides Scala doesn't optimize Mutual Recursion much, AFAIK - does it?

Comment: @AbhinavSharma No, optimization of mutual tail recursion is not supported out of the box.

Comment: @Jasper-M You mention, out of the box - is there some library that eases this task?

Comment: @AbhinavSharma https://github.com/wheaties/TwoTails

Comment: @Jasper-M thanks! These Typelevel folks are doing great stuff for Scala!